# Bullets not appearing in wordpress site

Tags: html, css, wordpress

When creating unordered lists the bullet points do not appear unless I manually apply css to the html.

```
style="padding-left: 30px; list-style: disc;"
```

What can I update so this no longer happens?  The example site is at the following url.

Comment: @paulsheldrake thanks for the edit. any ideas on how to resolve the IE issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove this in `style.css`

```
 1008  /*tabs*/
 1009  .tab-shortcode ul { /* list-style: none  */}
```

Comment: awesome that works for all browsers except for the dreaded IE.

Answer (score 0):

At line:1009 in you `.css` file remove

```
`.tab-shortcode ul {
  list-style: none;`
}
```